# EHCache implementation with Spring DAO

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am trying to implement EHCache with Spring DAO . I have a requirement where i need to show the same output when coming form 2nd JSP page to 1st JSP page , so ideally if i will put the data retrived earlier from database to the cache then i can retrieve it in stead of making database connection once again and bring the data .

Below is the list of JAR files with version i am using for EHCache

1. spring.jar
2. ehcache-core-2.2.0.jar
3. slf4j-api-1.6.0.jar
4. slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar
5. slf4j-jdk14-1.5.11.jar

BUt while building the application with ant script  i am getting "NoSuchMethodError" . Clearly that method in the JAR file . And when i am putting the proper jar file it is throwing error that some class is missing .

Can somebody suggest the exact version and list of JAR files for EHCache ? I am using JDK 1.6 .

Thanks

Satyajit

Comment: Wouldn't be simpler and easier to understand if you just passed the data from JSP1 to JSP2 (e.g. in the session), rather than messing about with caching?

Comment: Also, saying you got `NoSuchMethodError` is no use unless you tell what method wasn't found. Show us the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt resposne , give me soemtime i will build the application by checking in the code and will give you exact stack trace .

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is the problem (and details on what the missing method is will help), but it is odd that you have two slf4j implementation jars (log4j *and* jdk14). You also seem to be mixing 1.5 and 1.6 level slf4j jars which likely isn't a good idea.